# Get ADComputer foreach object and ask for MSSQL-Version

Tags: powershell

can you please help me?
I am just trying to get a list of all Servers on the Domain and for each server ask simultaneously which mssql server version is running on that server.

Thank you so much!

This is what a already have tried:

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter {OperatingSystem -Like "*Server*"} -Property \* | foreach object Sqlcmd -Q "SELECT @@VERSION" | foreach object | Format-Table Name,OperatingSystem -Wrap -Auto | Export-CSV AllWindows.csv -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```

I get this error:

```
The name "object" entered cannot be resolved to a method name.
```

Comment: I believe you'll need to use the `-S` flag on `SqlCmd` to query a remote host (assuming the connection is allowed) else, you would need to `Invoke-Command` to the remote hosts (assuming PS remoting is enabled)

Comment: It should be `-Properties` not `-Property`, also should just be the single asterisk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
$youradmincreds = Get-Credential
Get-ADComputer -Filter {OperatingSystem -Like "*Server*"} -Property * | %{
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $_.SamAccountName -Credential $youradmincreds -ScriptBlock {
        $version = Sqlcmd -Q "SELECT @@VERSION"
        $version | Format-Table Name,OperatingSystem -Wrap -Auto | Export-CSV AllWindows.csv -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
    }
}
```

edit: and if you've got ThreadJob module available (which you can also just get wtih find-module ThreadJob | install-module), you can speed the job up

```
$youradmincreds = Get-Credential
$job = Start-ThreadJob -ScriptBlock {
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $input -Credential $youradmincreds -ScriptBlock {
        $version = Sqlcmd -Q "SELECT @@VERSION"
        $version | Format-Table Name,OperatingSystem -Wrap -Auto | Export-CSV AllWindows.csv -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
    }
} -InputObject (Get-ADComputer -Filter {OperatingSystem -Like "*Server*"} | select -ExpandProperty SamAccountName)
$job | Wait-Job | Receive-Job
```